# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on bool

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin, prepared-statement

I want to add an Registration to my website but i always get this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on
>   bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\webseite\user.class.php:74 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\webseite\register.php(15): user->register() #1 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\webseite\user.class.php on line 74

Here is my register function:

```
public function register(){
    $con = new mysqli("localhost", "xxxxx", "password", "xxxxx");
    $error = false;
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $passwort = $_POST['passwort'];
    $passwort2 = $_POST['passwort2'];

    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo 'Bitte eine gültige E-Mail-Adresse eingeben<br>';
        $error = true;
    }     
    if(strlen($passwort) == 0) {
        echo 'Bitte ein Passwort angeben<br>';
        $error = true;
    }
    if($passwort != $passwort2) {
        echo 'Die Passwörter müssen übereinstimmen<br>';
        $error = true;
    }

    echo $email;
    if(!$error) { 
        $statement = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email");
        $result = $statement->execute(array('email' => $email));
        $user = $statement->fetch();

        if($user !== false) {
            echo 'Diese E-Mail-Adresse ist bereits vergeben<br>';
            $error = true;
        }    
    }

    if(!$error) {    
        $passwort_hash = password_hash($passwort, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $statement = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email, passwort, firstname, lastname) VALUES (:email, :passwort, :firstname, :lastanme)");
        $result = $statement->execute(array('email' => $email, 'passwort' => $passwort_hash));

        if($result) {        
            echo 'Du wurdest erfolgreich registriert. <a href="login.php">Zum Login</a>';
        } else {
            echo 'Beim Abspeichern ist leider ein Fehler aufgetreten<br>';
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: `$con->prepare()` failed for some reason and therefore returned `false`; so you're now attempting to do `false->execute()` ...

Answer (score 4):

`mysqli` does not support named parameters, you need question marks.

You also need to bind the parameters before you execute, you cannot send an array with values like in `PDO`.

So you need something like (for your first sql query):

```
$statement = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
$statement->bind_param("s", $email);
$result = $statement->execute();
```

Comment: ...and you also need get_result() before fetch and also fetch_assoc() instead of fetch()